LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected in spring webflux project
I keep getting leakbuffer error just by invoking my rest api, sometimes connection closed exception. I am not using any bytebuff exclusively in my code. I have rest api, on calling it should fetch flux of records from DB. And for each record, I aggreagate the data(again few more calls to DB) and build the response object. Finally it returns flux
Here is the my pom dependencies and code
I am using spring 3.3.0, Java 21, and using netty dependency and r2dbc dependecy like this.
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-native-macos</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-native-macos</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.110.Final</version>
        <classifier>osx-aarch_64</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-mssql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>reactor-netty-http-brave</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

My service class
    return myRepository.findItems(itemType, fromDate, toDate)
        .collectList()
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(buildError(404, ITEM_NOT_FOUND)))
        .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
        .flatMap(this::aggregateItemsData)
        .map(itemBuilder::toItemData)
        .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
            log.error(" getItems: {}", throwable.getMessage());
            return Mono.empty();
        });

I am not using any bytebuff operations, but I keep getting leakbuffer errof. I have no idea how to fix this and why I am getting this
     LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See https://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
Recent access records: 
Created at:
    

    io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:404)
        io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:188)
        io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:179)
        io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.buffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:116)
        io.r2dbc.mssql.codec.RpcEncoding.prepareBuffer(RpcEncoding.java:258)
        io.r2dbc.mssql.codec.RpcEncoding.lambda$encodeNull$2(RpcEncoding.java:181)
        io.r2dbc.mssql.codec.Encoded.getValue(Encoded.java:56)
        io.r2dbc.mssql.codec.ByteArray.fromEncoded(ByteArray.java:46)

